# Alfresco 3 Labs: Adding a thumbnail to a document

Tags: alfresco

Hey guys! Any Alfresco experts out there?

I have created a document type in Alfresco and am trying to associate it with an image -- Somehow. I don't really mind how it's done - an image uploader in the metadata section when saving the actual document would be nice, but I can live with having to upload the image first and then associating it somehow with the document.

Any ideas..?

Answer (score 1):

First read [how to create relationships between nodes](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide) (the nodes being a document and an image).

Then implement it within a [custom dialog](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Adding_a_Custom_Dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the thumbnail service?  It allows you to create thumbnails of documents / images.   This is [the official doc](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Thumbnail_Service) and a good [blog post here](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2009/03/03/913).

Even if you don't use it, you can take a look at how its content model works and implement something similar.